# When to call fork() and exec() by themselves?

Tags: system-calls, exec, fork

I'm learning about `fork()` and `exec()` commands. It seems like `fork()` and `exec()` are usually called together. (`fork()` creates a new child process, and `exec()` replaces the current process image with a new one.) However, in what scenarios might you call each function on its own? Are there scenarios like these?

Comment: Traditional forkbomb: while(1) fork(); to hog system resources.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure! A common pattern in "wrapper" programs is to do various things and then replace itself with some other program with only an `exec` call (no fork)

```
#!/bin/sh
export BLAH_API_KEY=blub
...
exec /the/thus/wrapped/program "$@"
```

A real-life example of this is `GIT_SSH` (though `git(1)` does also offer `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` if you do not want to do the above wrapper program method).

Fork-only is used when spawning a bunch of typically worker processes (e.g. Apache `httpd` in fork mode (though fork-only better suits processes that need to burn up the CPU and not those that twiddle their thumbs waiting for network I/O to happen)) or for [privilege separation](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html) used by `sshd` and other programs on OpenBSD (no exec)

```
$ doas pkg_add pstree
...
$ pstree | grep sshd
 |-+= 70995 root /usr/sbin/sshd
 | \-+= 28571 root sshd: jhqdoe [priv] (sshd)
 |   \-+- 14625 jhqdoe sshd: jhqdoe@ttyp6 (sshd)
```

The `root` sshd has on client connect forked off a copy of itself (28571) and then another copy (14625) for the privilege separation.

Answer (score 14):

There are plenty.

Programs that call `fork()` without `exec()` are usually following a pattern of spawning child *worker processes* for performing various tasks in separate processes to the main one.  You'll find this in programs as varied as `dhclient`, `php-fpm`, and `urxvtd`.

A program that calls `exec()` without `fork()` is *chain loading*, overlaying its process with a different program image.  There is a whole subculture of chain loading utilities that do particular things to process state and then execute another program to run with that revised process state.  Such utilities are common in the [daemontools family](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html) of service and system management toolsets, but are not limited to those.  A few examples:

- [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) from Gerrit Pape's [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)
- [`s6-softlimit`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-softlimit.html) and [`s6-envdir`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-envdir.html) from Laurent Bercot's [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/)
- [`local-reaper`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/local-reaper.html) and [`move-to-control-group`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/move-to-control-group.html) from my [nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/)
- `rdprio` and `idprio` on FreeBSD
- [`numactl`](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/libnuma/) on FreeBSD and Linux

The daemontools family toolsets have *a lot* of such tools, from [`machineenv`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/machineenv.html) through [`find-matching-jvm`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/find-matching-jvm.html) to [`runtool`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runtool.8).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, debuggers, using `ptrace`, typically make use of the gap between `fork` and `exec`. A debuggee should mark itself with `PTRACE_TRACEME` to indicate that it is being traced by its parent process - the debugger. This is to give required permissions to the debugger.

So a debugger would first fork itself. The child would call `ptrace` with `PTRACE_TRACEME` and then call `exec`. Whichever program the child exec's will now be traceable by the parent.

Comment: There are many examples of doing things between fork and exec, the most common being redirecting I/O (e.g. setting up pipes). But the question is about doing fork without any exec at all.

Answer (score 0):

#### exec without fork

There are at least two reasons why you would want to do such a thing:

1. Chain loading. The current process image is replaced with something different.
2. Restarting the currently running program (might for example happen when you SIGHUP or such a server process, reloading everything and doing a completely fresh start). In some way, one could argue this is chain loading, only coincidentially with the same program.

#### fork without exec

That's what every daemon does every time it's started (twice, indeed). This does several things, among them the shell doesn't hang (since the original process that the shell waits on terminates) and the daemon is no longer controlled by the terminal, so closing the shell window doesn't kill the daemon.

Another common use is forking worker children, which was made famous by the apache web server some 25 years ago (nowadays this isn't considered state of the art any more due to being very prone to the thundering herd problem, but it sure provides the darn simplest, most robust server possible).

Yet another common use is to create a consistent snapshot. `fork` not only creates a process, it also copies (in theory, in reality it only marks pages copy-on-write) the address space. This (atomically) creates a snapshot of the complete program data which the parent can no longer modify.
Some programs take advantage of that. For example redis saves data to disk (in a consistent state) while at the same time *modifying* the data set concurrently. This only works because `fork` created a consistent snapshot that doesn't see the modifications made by the parent process.

Comment: It's actually very few dæmons nowadays, with most not doing this as standard or having a commonly-used mode not to. [It is a mistake to fork](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotBackgroundise) leading to [readiness mismatch](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html#Mismatch) and [horrors](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/), and is one of the mistakes of [the dæmonization fallacy](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/bsd-service-command.html#Inheritance). This mistake has at long last widely fallen out of favour.