# How can one check in one's program if it is a service process that was started by systemd?

Tags: systemd, services

Is there a documented way to check, **from within the code of the program running as the service itself**, that it has been started by `systemd` (as opposed to being started from within an interactive login session, from cron, etc.)?

My current solution is to define an environment variable in the `.service` unit (`Environment=...`) and check for its existence in my code.  But there may be something directly available.

Comment: If you don't wrongly conflate prompts with shells and shells with login sessions, not only is the question clearer but you are halfway to an answer.

Comment: If your process is owned by a service and not some overarching scope, it's a safe bet that it was started by that service.

Comment: @JdeBP: sorry but I do not understand. I can start my program either from a prompt (a login session), or via a non-login session such as a cron entry - so checking for a login/non-login environment  not enough. I need to check if the program was started as part of a systemd service. It would help if your comment was more clear on what to check for.

Comment: @muru: I realized that the question was not clear enough, fixed that. While the duplicate you mention is useful, it deals with a check outside of the code. I will use it, though, if there is no more straightforward way (by walking the PIDs in my code)

Comment: A prompt is not a shell, nor is a shell a login session.  Get the concepts right in what you ask, and not only will you have a clearer question that is halfway to an answer, you'll _also_ see the conceptual error in what you just wrote about cron jobs.

Comment: @JdeBP: would "how can the running program check whether it was started by a systemd unit" fine for you?

Comment: It doesn't address the part where you are doing the conflation.  Here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One cannot.

Everything that systemd provides to a process invoked for a service — its arguments, its environment, the control group(s) containing it, its resource limits, its open file descriptors — can be and is done by other service managers, too.  Moreover, there is no shared convention for identifying what service manager is managing services; no conventional environment variables, nor other markers.

### Erroneous mechanisms

You might be thinking of checking the executable name of the parent process.  This is a non-starter, for the reasons expounded in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196252/5132 .  The name of the executable program image of the parent process (for system-wide services) will be `/sbin/init` on Debian Linux operating systems, because Debian has the convention of that being an alternatives-style symbolic link to the actual process 1 program image file, and the the `/init` program in the initramfs only needing to know that one name.

You might be thinking that, despite what I just wrote, control groups are a systemd marker.  They are not.  Here's the control group tree of a service process being managed by a completely different service manager, `service-manager` from the nosh toolset:

```
% systemd-cgls /system.slice/service-manager.service/tinydns@.service
Control group /system.slice/service-manager.service/tinydns@.service:
└─tinydns@127.53.0.1.service
  └─1433 tinydns
%
```

The `tinydns` program, finding a control group in `/proc/self/cgroup`, has no justification for assuming that systemd set up that control group.  It was actually set up by the `move-to-control-group` utility:

```
% cat /var/local/sv/tinydns@127.53.0.1/service/run
#!/bin/nosh
#Run file generated from ./tinydns@.socket
#DNS/UDP socket on 127.53.0.1
udp-socket-listen --systemd-compatibility --combine4and6 127.53.0.1 domain
move-to-control-group "../tinydns@.service/tinydns@127.53.0.1.service"
envdir env
envuidgid -- tinydns-d
setlogin -- tinydns-d
hardlimit -d 3000000
softlimit -d hard
./service
%
```

No other process state changes are unique to systemd. Environment variables can be set with `setenv` (the chain-loading tool) `userenv`, `machineenv`, or `export` (the chain-loading tool), resource limits with `softlimit`, `ulimit` (the chain-loading tool), or `s6-softlimit`, open file descriptors with `redirfd` or `fdredir`, namespaces with `unshare`, scheduling priorities with `rtprio` or `chrt`, NUMA policy with `numactl`; and so forth.

systemd is not the only speaker of the `LISTEN_FDS` protocol, as can be seen from the aforegiven.  `INVOCATION_ID` is likewise just an exercise in populating `env/INVOCATION_ID` at the start of a `run` program and chaining through `envdir`.  None of these are reliable as markers.

### Conceptual errors

There's also the flaw that you want to exclude processes started by `cron`.  The conceptual flaw here is that `cron` is a service, and the processes that it spawns *are running in the context of that service*.  There is *no* magic distinction between a process spawned by the `cron` process in the `cron` service and a process spawned by some other service process in some other service, that makes the former somehow distinguishable from the latter.

Rid yourself of this conceptual error, and an answer appears.  The thing that distinguishes dæmons is that the (POSIX) sessions that they belong to do not have controlling terminals, and they have no *other* associations (from the name set by `setlogin`, through systemd's user-space login session mechanism, to various security contexts) with any login session.  There's not a portable direct way to query what the controlling terminal of a session is, but noting that opening `/dev/tty` fails is an available indirect route.  Note that some superficially promising C library functions are actually unreliable in practice.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398951/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187540/5132
- [How to get the real name of the controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187319/)
- toolsets:

  - [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - [execline](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/).*  Softwares.
- reference manuals:

  - [`export`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/export.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *execline*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`redirfd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/redirfd.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *execline*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-softlimit`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-softlimit.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6*.  skarnet.org.
  - [chpst](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html).  runit.  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`service-manager`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/service-manager.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`move-to-control-group`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/move-to-control-group.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`setenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/setenv.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`softlimit`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/softlimit.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`ulimit`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/ulimit.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`fdredir`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/fdredir.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`unshare`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/unshare.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`setlogin`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/setlogin.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use the following command:

```
#> systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
cups.path                                  enabled        
accounts-daemon.service                    enabled        
anacron.service                            enabled        
apparmor.service                           enabled        
atd.service                                enabled        
autovt@.service                            enabled        
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled        
...
```

By itself `systemctl list-unit-files` list all installed unit files that may start a service. The ones labeled as `enabled` are the one started at the time you type the command.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my question, I would like to check it from within the  program

Comment: Do you mean from the unit file itself ?

Comment: `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`

Comment: @jasonwryan: Damn... so simpler...

Comment: @perror: I realized that I was not clear enough, I clarified in the question. I meant from within the code of the program started in the service

Comment: I think I got it, so you want it to be in C, I guess. Isn't it?